# Handling JSON object on Python server results in 'list' object has no attribute 'read' error

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have javascript code that pulls data and creates a JSON object(s) to send to a server;

```
for (i=0;i<selected.length;i++)
{
    if (selected[i].value == "available")
    {
        //Add item to the selectedjsonObj list
        //alert("The new select ID is: " + selected[i].text);
        selectedjsonObj[selected[i].text] = selected[i].text;
        selected[i].value = "selected";
        selectedChange++;
    }
}

for (i=0;i<available.length;i++)
{
    if (available[i].value == "selected")
    {
        //Add item to the availablejsonObj list
        //alert("The new available ID is: " + available[i].text);
        availablejsonObj[available[i].text] = available[i].text;
        available[i].value = "available";
        availableChange++;
    }
}
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {  
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("title_msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        // var el = document.getElementById('userid_msg');
        if (xmlhttp.responseText=="Updated") {
            document.getElementById("title_msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else {
            alert("An error occurred saving your changes.  Please refresh the page and try again.");
            document.getElementById("title_msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
var x=document.forms["cohort"]["title"].value;
if (selectedChange && availableChange) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/update/cohortfriends?a=" + JSON.stringify(availablejsonObj) + "&s=" + JSON.stringify(selectedjsonObj) + "&t=" + x, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
if (selectedChange) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/update/cohortfriends?s=" + JSON.stringify(selectedjsonObj) + "&t=" + x, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
if (availableChange) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/update/cohortfriends?a=" + JSON.stringify(availablejsonObj) + "&t=" + x, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
document.getElementById("save_cohort_friends").innerHTML="No Changes";
```

On the server I try to read the object as follows (only showing one of the blocks of code for processing the JSON object(s);

```
    removed_friends = json.load(self.request.get_all("a"))
    for key, value in removed_friends.iteritems():
        logging.debug("Processing the Removed_Friend Value: %s" % value)
        logging.debug("With the Key of: %s" % key)
        Cohorts.remove_friend_from_Cohort(my_lhcohort, User.by_id_name(value), cohort_key)
```

This is getting the a - 'list' object has no attribute 'read' - error on the

removed_friends = json.load(self.request.get_all("a")) statement.

Since I am new to python and javascript and am self taught, I am sure that I am doing something conceptually wrong.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `request.get_all` is giving you a `list`, which is not a valid argument to `json.load`. You will need to iterate over that list and process each element in it separately.

Comment: I have been using get_all through-out my code.  I guess that is why I had to add [0] to process my parameters.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick responses. The responses not only fixed my issue, but cleared up some muddled thinking of mine.  Now I need to clean up some of my other code.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

> load(fp, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None,
>   parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)
>       Deserialize `fp` (a `.read()`-supporting file-like object containing
>       a JSON document) to a Python object.

So json.load is expecting a file-like object, not a `list`, which `request.get_all` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You give a list to `json.load` which causes this error.

Moreover, use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`.

Try this:

```
info = json.dumps(self.request.get_all("a"))
removed_friends = json.loads(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_all` function returns all the values for the query string parameter `a`. Since you only have one `a`, you should use `get` instead. Also, use `json.loads` to parse a string as json.

```
removed_friends = json.loads(self.request.get("a"))
#                     here ^       and here ^
```